# Trouble Importing Eclipse Project into Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

While trying to import an eclipse project, I get the following prompt:

[image: error]

The project was sent to me as a zip file, so I don't have a workspace. What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Where are you trying to import the project from? Does that path match the folder you unzipped the project?

Comment: I unzipped the project to my desktop. I have also tried unzipping to the AndroidStudioProjects folder, but I still get the prompt.